# how to edit pg_hba.conf using gedit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, sudo

I am trying to make changes to my pg_hba.conf file. I `cd /etc/postgresql/9.1/main`

```
$ sudo gedit pg_hba.conf
```

make my changes, but then the directory looks like this:

```
$ ls
environment  pg_hba.conf~     start.conf
pg_ctl.conf  pg_ident.conf
pg_hba.conf  postgresql.conf
```

What way can I edit pg_hba.conf without this double file business? If I don't run sudo I get an error in gedit that I don't have permissions necessary to open the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files ending with a `~` (tilde) are backup files. Gedit creates them, you can switch that off in the gedit preferences under *File saving*.

Or you can use an editor that does not leave those files around, like `nano`.